# time limits in uploading large files

Tags: django, minio, fileserver

I want to access users to upload large files to the Django server but my timeout is 50s.
I'm using the Minio server so the first user should upload the file to the Django server and then files copies from the Django server to the Minio server using internal IPs.
what can I do?